# Catch SqlException when Attempting NHibernate Transaction

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, nhibernate, exception

I need to see an errorcode produced by a `SqlException` - however, I can't get one to fire.  I use NHibernate and have a `SQL UNIQUE CONSTRAINT` setup on my table.  When that constraint is violated, I need to catch the error code and produce a user-friendly message based off of that. Here is a sample of my try/catch:

```
using (var txn = NHibernateSession.Current.BeginTransaction()) {
    try {
        Session["Report"] = report;
        _reportRepository.SaveOrUpdate(report);
        txn.Commit();
        Fetch(null, report.ReportId, string.Empty);
    } catch (SqlException sqlE) {
        var test = sqlE.ErrorCode;
        ModelState.AddModelError("name", Constants.ErrorMessages.InvalidReportName);
        return Fetch(report, report.ReportId, true.ToString());
    } catch (InvalidStateException ex) {
        txn.Rollback();
        ModelState.AddModelErrorsFrom(ex, "report.");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        txn.Rollback();
        ModelState.AddModelError(String.Empty, Constants.ErrorMessages.GeneralSaving);
    }
}
```

Please pardon my ignorance.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[Check this out](http://ayende.com/blog/archive/2009/10/22/database-independence-with-nhibernate.aspx) which illustrates how to catch a `GenericADOException` and look at the `InnerException` property:

```
catch (GenericADOException ex)
{
    txn.Rollback();
    var sql = ex.InnerException as SqlException;
    if (sql != null && sql.Number == 2601)
    {
        // Here's where to handle the unique constraint violation
    }
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Instead of catching a SqlException directly in your controller, I'd set up a [SQLExceptionConverter](http://fabiomaulo.blogspot.com/2009/06/improving-ado-exception-management-in.html) to translate it to a more meaningful exception.